# I've tried any way. SUPER PRIVILEGE CANNOT BE GRANTED I tried set log_bin_trust_function_creators

Tags: mysql, server, rds

I tried

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin_trust_function_creators';
+---------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                   | Value |
+---------------------------------+-------+
| log_bin_trust_function_creators | ON    |
+---------------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can see that it is well set up.
Then it restarted the RDS.
The database has been refreshed several times.
In addition, the following can be identified:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User='new_root' and Host='%'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  Host: %
                  User: new_root
           Select_priv: Y
           Insert_priv: Y
           Update_priv: Y
           Delete_priv: Y
           Create_priv: Y
             Drop_priv: Y
           Reload_priv: Y
         Shutdown_priv: N
          Process_priv: Y
             File_priv: N
            Grant_priv: Y
       References_priv: Y
            Index_priv: Y
            Alter_priv: Y
          Show_db_priv: Y
            Super_priv: N
 Create_tmp_table_priv: Y
      Lock_tables_priv: Y
          Execute_priv: Y
       Repl_slave_priv: Y
      Repl_client_priv: Y
      Create_view_priv: Y
        Show_view_priv: Y
   Create_routine_priv: Y
    Alter_routine_priv: Y
      Create_user_priv: Y
            Event_priv: Y
          Trigger_priv: Y
Create_tablespace_priv: N
              ssl_type:
            ssl_cipher:
           x509_issuer:
          x509_subject:
         max_questions: 0
           max_updates: 0
       max_connections: 0
  max_user_connections: 0
                plugin: mysql_native_password
 authentication_string: *5EDA56336D7A85D9D6FC7EEBFE91E063ACD5A87E
      password_expired: N
 password_last_changed: 2020-03-12 06:25:00
     password_lifetime: NULL
        account_locked: N
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL privileges ON *.* TO 'new_root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'new_root'@'%' (using password: YES)
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Super_Priv='Y' WHERE user='new_root' AND host='%';
ERROR 1644 (45000): SUPER PRIVILEGE CANNOT BE GRANTED
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Asia/Seoul';
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

I finally tried to change global time.
Only hopeless emotions soar.
What's piled up on the stream had a lot of relevant information, but I don't know if my search is poor or unusual.
I stayed awake for five hours to change this global time.
Can you help me? I'm very, very tired.

My mysql version is...

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+------------+
| VERSION()  |
+------------+
| 5.7.26-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You seem to have missed **ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'new_root'@'%' (using password: YES)**. You clearly can't update anything or set anything when your access has been denied.

Comment: @Ken White Thank you for your answer. So how can I allow access?

Answer (score 0):

I solved.
If you use RDS, it doesn't seem like you have full authority like localhost.
I solved the problem by changing the `time_zone` in the parameter group, instead of the original attempt of using `SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Asia/Seoul'`.

Comment: I hope to be of help to someone who has similar difficulties with me.
Change the time_zone in the parameter group, plus https://aws.amazon.com/ko/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/error-1227-mysqldump/
If does not solve the problem with , check the parameter group.